# Why is Rieman Curvature tensor a (1,3) tensor?

Tags: definition, riemannian-geometry

First for the covariant derivative in local coordinates:

$$\nabla_XY = (X^i\partial_i Y^k + X^i Y^j \Gamma_{ij}^k)\partial_k$$

So the basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$ requires $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ as in put.

The Riemann Curvature tensor has term say $\nabla_X \nabla_Y Z$. The map is $(T_pM \times T_pM \times T_pM) \to T_p(M)$, There are only three arguments it doesn't send to $\mathbb{R}$, so how can it be a $(3,1)$ tensor?

Comment: Note that the map's output is a vector, not a scalar.

Comment: Right, so how can it be tensor in the first place then?

Comment: If you want a map to scalars, apply a covector ($1$-form).

Comment: You mean take $\omega$ a 1-form and $\omega(R(X,Y),Z)?$ Where is this encoded when we define $R(X,Y)Z$? I don't see how this is clear.

Comment: Because now we have $(T_pM)_3 \stackrel{R}\to T_pM \stackrel{\omega}\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Note that a vector is a tensor. It can be considered as a map that sends the covector to a scalar, namely the scalar obtained by applying the covector to the vector (this is a natural map from a vector space to its double dual; for finite-dimensional vector spaces this is a natural isomorphism, that is, you can identify the vector space with its double dual).

Comment: The Riemann curvature tensor is a $(1, 3)$  tensor, which means that it's a linear map from **three** vectors to **one** vector.

Comment: So basically we are saying $(T_pM)_3 \stackrel{R}\to T_pM \stackrel{\phi}\approx (T_pM)^{**} = \mathbb{R}$, where $x \in T_pM$ and $\phi \in (T_pM)^*$, $\psi(x)(\phi) = \phi(x) \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Kevin, i thought we can only call it a "tensor map" if it is multilinear map ($\to \mathbb{R})$

Comment: Can't edit comment. Above map should be $(T_pM)_3 \stackrel{R}\to T_pM \stackrel{\psi}\approx (T_pM)^{**} = \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Hawk Well, the definition I know is of the form $R :  \Gamma(TM)\times \Gamma(TM)\times \Gamma(TM)\to C^\infty(M)$

Comment: @Kevin even in your definition, it still lands in $C^\infty(M)$, not quite $\mathbb{R}$ unless you look at $f\in C^\infty(M)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading your comments and your question, I believe there are two primary sources for your confusion.

1. The Riemann curvature is not a *tensor*, it is a *tensor field*. (Often people use the word tensor when they mean tensor field.)
2. In fact, the Riemann curvature is not technically a $(1,3)$-tensor field either, we require an identification $$\hom(V\times V \times V \times V^*,\mathbb R) \cong \hom(V\times V \times V, V).$$

I will now explain these in more detail. A *tensor* is an element of $$V\otimes\cdots\otimes V\otimes V^*\otimes\cdots \otimes V^*.$$ Tensors only make sense given some vector space $V$. However, the Riemann curvature is defined in terms of a connection! It doesn't just exist on a single tangent space, it exists on the entire manifold. The Riemann curvature is not a tensor, instead, it is a *tensor field*. In other words, it is a smooth section of a tensor bundle. While a tensor takes vectors and dual vectors as inputs and real numbers as outputs, a tensor field takes vector fields as inputs and outputs smooth real valued functions. That is, if the base manifold is $M$,
$$T:\Gamma(TM) \times \cdots \times \Gamma(TM)\times\Gamma(T^*M)\times\cdots\times\Gamma(T^*M)\to C^{\infty}(M).$$
Now let's look at the specific case of the Riemann curvature. We find that the domain and codomain are
$$R:\Gamma(TM) \times \Gamma(TM)\times \Gamma(TM) \to \Gamma(TM).$$
You might say - hey that's not a tensor field! The codomain is wrong! But we now have access to a natural isomorphism as stated above. Specifically, on each tangent space, the isomorphism is
\begin{align*}\varphi :\hom(V\times V \times V, V) &\to \hom(V\times V \times V \times V^*, \mathbb R)\\
L &\mapsto [(u,v,w,\omega)\mapsto \omega(L(u,v,w))]
\end{align*}
This isomorphism can be used to show that there is a natural identification of the Riemann curvature with some tensor field $\widehat R$:
$$\widehat R:\Gamma(TM) \times \Gamma(TM)\times \Gamma(TM) \times \Gamma(T^*M)\to C^{\infty}(M).$$
Because we have access to this natural isomorphism, many maps (e.g. linear endomorphisms) can be identified with tensors/tensor fields, and we refer to all of them as tensors.

Comment: Why don’t we count the image of L as a new vector space and omega really takes on 4 arguments even though it is a “ dummy” space

Comment: Can you expand on your question? I'm not sure if I understand it. Anyway the image of L is a vector, and omega maps vectors to real numbers.